# How to fix EXIF orientation on before upload with angular-file-upload

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I am using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) directive to upload files, I have problem with images or photos taken with apple devices, I understand that apple include exif orientation data on image to correct view on apple devices, but when these images are uploaded on web app the orientation is wrong for browsers.

I am using this directive in several views on my app, for time reazon change to another like ng-file-upload is not the best option.

There are some other directives that fix this problem like [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) but I want to know how to fix this issue with onBeforeUploadItem event of angular-file-upload.

Answer (score 0):

Now I solved it.

here's what I do.

Here's the code in html:

`<input id="upload_button" type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple/>`

and

`<img ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" ng-src="{{pic}}" height="100%" />`

then in controller:

`var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
$scope.pic = "";`

```
    var target = evt.dataTransfer || evt.target;
    var file = target && target.files && target.files[0];
    var options = {
        canvas: true
    };

    var displayImg = function(img) {
        $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
            $scope.pic = img.toDataURL();
            $scope.rotatedFile = dataURItoBlob($scope.pic);
        });
    };

    loadImage.parseMetaData(file, function(data) {
        if (data.exif) {
            options.orientation = data.exif.get('Orientation');
        }
        loadImage(file, displayImg, options);
    });

};
angular.element(document.querySelector('#upload_button')).on('change', handleFileSelect);

var dataURItoBlob = function(dataURI) {
        var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
            array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: mimeString});
    };`
```

and then, before upload:

```
uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
        $log.debug('onBeforeUploadItem', item);

        item._file = $scope.rotatedFile;
    };
```

and you need [loader-image.min.js](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidxaPi4qHLAhVLG5oKHc4nAzQQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fblueimp%2FJavaScript-Load-Image&usg=AFQjCNHDO-77dvpxkOT0tYMXozKFc8-R5A&bvm=bv.115339255,d.bGs), [ng-img-crop.js](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop/blob/master/source/js/ng-img-crop.js) and `[ngImgCrop]` in app.js

And that's it.

I hope it helps you.